# Pushout square of groups, and group cohomology

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Suppose that we have (not necessarily injective) group homomorphisms $H \to G_1$ and $H \to G_2$, and we construct the pushout $G_1 \sqcup_H G_2$. Suppose we have a representation $V$ of the pushout group $G_1 \sqcup_H G_2$. We can of course restrict the representation along the maps in the pushout square (I'll just denote these by $V$ as well). In this case, can we obtain some relationship between the group cohomology groups $\mathrm{H}^\bullet(H;V)$, $\mathrm{H}^\bullet(G_i;V)$, and $\mathrm{H}^\bullet(G_1 \sqcup_H G_2;V)$, perhaps using a long exact sequence?

(In case it matters, for my purposes $V$ will be a finite-dimensional real vector space.)

Comment: Have you looked into what happens when the maps are injective? For example, Section II.7 of Brown's book *Cohomology of groups* is about the homology in this case.